# How to modify the directory of a compute instance in PieCloudDB Database

Tags: deployment, directory

I have deployed a Cloud On Cloud version of PieCloudDB Database in private cloud environment. During runtime, I noticed that the compute instance directories are located under the /data directory of each node. I would like to know how can I specify the compute instance directories to be located in pre-created directories of my choice.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named "data.yaml" first.

If you want to modify the mount directory for all nodes to be the same, you can refer to the example below and rewrite it in the data.yaml file.

```
nodePathMap:  
  - node: DEFAULT_PATH_FOR_NON_LISTED_NODES  
    paths:  
      - /data1
```

If you need different nodes to specify different paths, you can modify data.yaml as follows:

```
nodePathMap:  
  - node: DEFAULT_PATH_FOR_NON_LISTED_NODES  
    paths:  
      - /data1  
  - node: k8s-dev1  
    paths:  
      - /data1  
      - /data2
```

After preparing the data.yaml file, execute the following command to update:

```
helm upgrade localpv pieclouddb/localpv --reuse-values -n openpie-helm -f data.yaml
```

Then，when you create a new virtual data warehouse in PieCloudDB Database, the data directories for the compute instances will be written to the newly specified localpv.